# Why is COUNT(CASE WHEN...) seemingly stopping full MYSQL query retrieval?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table called "guesses" that stores peoples guesses whether a baby is a boy or a girl.  Those are the two possible things in the "sex" column (i.e. "boy" or "girl).

There are 4 guesses in the table for this poolid.  So if I run this code below...

```
    $sql = "SELECT 
    FROM guesses
    WHERE poolid = '$poolid'
    ORDER BY $sort, createddate";
        $getguesses = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (!$getguesses) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        } else {
            //Get total number of guesses
            $numguesses=mysqli_num_rows($getguesses);   
            echo "NUMGUESSES:  $numguesses";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getguesses)) {
//code to grab other info about guesses, not relevant, works fine
                }
        }
```

It outputs

```
NUMGUESSES: 4
```

And also spits out 4 lines (one for each guess) with other info that isn't relevant.

I would like to count the total number of girl guesses vs. boy guesses, for use later in a pie chart.  So I did the following...

```
    $sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN `sex` = 'girl' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'totalgirls', COUNT(CASE WHEN `sex` = 'boy' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'totalboys'
    FROM guesses
    WHERE poolid = '$poolid'
    ORDER BY $sort, createddate";
        $getguesses = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (!$getguesses) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        } else {
            //Get total number of guesses
            $numguesses=mysqli_num_rows($getguesses);   
            echo "NUMGUESSES:  $numguesses";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getguesses)) {
                        echo "GIRLS:".  $row['totalgirls'];
                        echo "BOYS:".  $row['totalboys'];
               //code to grab other info about guesses, not relevant
                }
         }
```

This outputs

```
NUMGUESSES: 1
GIRLS: 4
BOYS: 0
```

And also spits out ONLY ONE line (for only one of the four existing guesses)

All four guesses are girls, so the GIRLS total and the BOYS total are correct.  But why is it only seeing NUMGUESSES as 1 now?  It should be 4 and should show 4 lines of guesses.

Something with the COUNT() is throwing something off.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking mysql to count, so it outputs one line  ; )
Try this instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(CASE WHEN `sex` = 'girl' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as.....
```

Beware of including NULL values in a count!

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't work, just outputted NUMGUESSES:  1, GIRLS:4, BOYS:4 and only one line again

Comment: The variable $numguesses counts the number of rows in your recordset, it will always be 1! ANd since you're perfoming a COUNT, having ony one row is what's expected... what would the other rows contain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding why you say it will always be 1.  When you use COUNT in a query, the results are always 1 row, no matter what?  So would I then be forced to do two separate SQL queries (1 that gets all the info in as many rows as there are and 1 to do the counting)?  I really thought you could do them both in the same query, but I must be wrong.

Comment: Yes, COUNT aggregates results. And no, you don't need two separate queries: if you use SELECT COUNT(*) as grandTotal instead of SELECT *, your first field in the resulting recordset will contain the total number of rows where poolid = '$poolid'. Then, you fetch that total from within the recordset ($row['grandTotal']). Your WHILE loop will get executed only once, and that's fine, you have all the numbers you need  ; )

Comment: Makes sense, but I also do WANT the while loop to loop as many times as needed to get me all my other information for each individual guess (guesser's firstname, guesser's lastname, etc).  Sorry, I'm pretty sure I didn't explain enough upfront which is probably driving you nuts haha.  Basically, i want to loop through and bring back all info for every row for that poolid (whether it's 4 rows or 400 rows) but I decided that I'd also like to kill two birds and get the totalgirls and totalboys guesses in the same query. I'll do them separately, was just hoping it could be done more efficiently